# Javascript error - document.getElementsById is not a function

Tags: javascript

Since I am calling this code in loop. But following code is giving me error as `document.getElementsById`  is not a function. What should I do how can I call doc.getbyid in loop.

```
for (var z=1; z < i; z++){
       var textbox = document.getElementsById("a"+z).value;
       var textbox2 = document.getElementsById("b").value;
       var textbox3 = document.getElementsById("c").value;
       alert(textbox);
       alert(textbox2);
       alert(textbox3);
}
```

Comment: What is your requirement ? What is the name of textbox you are looking for using document.getElementsById ???

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's because it `getElementById` (note the lack of the "s" on "Element"). Which makes sense if you think about it, because `id` values have to be unique in a document, so there will be only one "element" that matches, rather than multiple "elements".

However, there are methods that return multiple elements which do use the plural "elements", such as `getElementsByTagName`, so you may just be mixing them up.

Answer (score 4):

The function is not getElementsById but getElementById.

There is no plural form on Element

Answer (score 2):

Actually you need to use as follows:

```
for (var z = 1; z < i; z++) { 
    var textbox = document.getElementById("a"+z).value; 
    var textbox2 = document.getElementById("b").value; 
    var textbox3 = document.getElementById("c").value; 
    alert(textbox); 
    alert(textbox2); 
    alert(textbox3); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The name of the function is `getElementById`.

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsById()` is not the function but `document.getElementById()` is. If you want to get all of the tag names, you can use `document.getElementsByTagName()` and if you want to get specific class elements you can use `document.getElementsByClassName()`.