# Javascript: getElementById vs getElementsById (both works on different pages)

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm struggling with a really weird problem...

I have two pages (quite the sames) where I need to disable some selects. On one of them (say page A), I use getElementById to retrieve my element, and on the second one (say page B) I use getElement**s**ById (with a 's') to retrieve it (and it works on both cases).

What is weird is that if I use getElement**s**ById on page A (with the 's'), it gives me the error "document.getElementsById is not a function", which is normal because this function (with the 's') normally doesn't exist. But I don't have this error on page B, and if I use getElementById (without the 's') on this page, it **doesn't** works !?!?

Can someone give me an explanation ? (I'll lose the few hairs left on my head if it continue ...)

Thanks in advance!

Ps: Sorry for my poor english!

Edit: Here is the code of my pages:

**Page A:**

```
function controleDelaiFranchise (casChoix){
        var estAvecGarantie = <bean:write property="avecGarantie" name="simulationAutonomeForm" filter="false"/>;

        if(estAvecGarantie ==true){

            if(casChoix == 'Emprunteur'){
                document.getElementById("assDelaiFranchiseEmpr").disabled = false;
            }
            else {
                if(casChoix == 'CoEmprunteur'){
                    document.getElementById("assDelaiFranchiseCoEmpr").disabled = false;
                }
            } 
        }
        else{

            if(casChoix == 'Emprunteur'){
                document.getElementsById("assDelaiFranchiseEmpr").disabled = true;
            }
            else {
                if(casChoix == 'CoEmprunteur'){
                    document.getElementById("assDelaiFranchiseCoEmpr").disabled = true;
                }
            } 
        }
```

**Page B:**

```
function controleDelaiFranchise (casChoix){
        var estAvecGarantie = document.getElementsByName("estAvecGarantie")[0].value;

        if(estAvecGarantie){

            if(casChoix == 'Emprunteur'){
                document.getElementsById("assDelaiFranchiseEmpr").disabled = false;
            }
            else {
                if(casChoix == 'CoEmprunteur'){
                    document.getElementsById("assDelaiFranchiseCoEmpr").disabled = false;
                }
            } 
        } else {

            if(casChoix == 'Emprunteur'){
                document.getElementsById("assDelaiFranchiseEmpr").disabled = true;
            }
            else {
                if(casChoix == 'CoEmprunteur'){
                    document.getElementsById("assDelaiFranchiseCoEmpr").disabled = true;
                }
            } 
        }

    }
```

**Edit 2:**

Ok so when it was not working on page B (without 's') I had

```
var estAvecGarantie = document.getElementsByName("estAvecGarantie")[0].value;
if(estAvecGarantie){ ... }
```

I replace it with

```
var estAvecGarantie = document.getElementsByName("estAvecGarantie")[0].value;
if(estAvecGarantie == true) { ... }
```

and now it works using getElementById without the 's'

But I still don't understand why it's still working with this damn 's' ... So my problem is solved (ish), but still, if someone have an explanation for why can I used getElement**s**byId() even if the function doesn't exist (and specifically on one page only), I'm all ears because I hate when I don't understand ...

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Has somebody monkey patched `document` on your second page? `document.getElementsById = document.getElementById; document.getElementById = undefined;`?

Comment: Please define "it doesn't work" Do you get the same error, or what actually happens?

Comment: @Teemu : On page B when i us document.getElementsById("assDelaiFranchiseEmpr").disabled = false; the element is actually disabled, but when I use document.getElementById("assDelaiFranchiseEmpr").disabled = false; it does nothing (not even an error message). I tried on debug mod, document.getElementsById("assDelaiFranchiseEmpr") return the element, but not with document.getElementById("assDelaiFranchiseEmpr") ...

Comment: @nad : The only reason is because I was using getElementsByClass and I forgot the 's' when I changed it... Now I just need to know why is it working with this 's' on this specific page but not without (especially because there is no such method as getElementsById with a 's'...)

Comment: Hmm... Most likely there is an element with `id` of `assDelaiFranchiseEmpr`, but it's not an element having native `disabled` property. Please give us an [mcve], otherwise this question will probably be closed in the future.

Comment: @Teemu : It's the same element on both pages, a basic select... And it work on both, with an 's' on the method on page B and without 's' on page A

Comment: Then a reproducible example is the only way you could get an answer, there's some monkey patching going on, as deceze has explained in his comment above.

Comment: @deceze No apparently there is no monkey patching anywhere ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As described by `James` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885639/javascript-error-document-getelementsbyid-is-not-a-function) *id values have to be unique in a document, so there will be only one "element" that matches, rather than multiple "elements".*

That is the reason, We should not use **s** while selecting elements. As `Id` can be selected only one at a time.

However, there are methods that return multiple elements which do use the plural "elements", such as `getElementsByTagName`.

Hope that clears your confusion

Comment: *"We should not use s"* – Well, or rather, `getElement_s_ById` flat out doesn't exist in any standard.

Comment: ahh, exactly..! Just helping the OP with his confusion. Even i didn't thought of `getElement_s_ById` Thanks.

Comment: I guess the point of the question is: "_getElementsById on page A ... gives ... error ... But I don't have this error on page B_". Or just my poor english, (or a poor description?).

Comment: and somewhat answer is, the OP is automatically creating issue for himself by using `s`. Instead try using the standard keyword which will work in both the page.

Comment: @nad Nope, please read the question, OP says: "_...  if I use getElementbyId (without the 's') on this page [B], it doesn't work_".

Comment: then, there might be issue with something else. I guess, I cleared his doubt as why not to use `s` while selecting the elements.

Comment: I know that there is no such method as getElement_s_ById... My question is why is it working with an 's' on this page and not without ... It's driving me crazy!

Answer (score 2):

**First things first:**
Function-, or rather, methodnames in JavaScript are Case-Sensitive. This means that document.getElementById is not the same as document.getElementbyId.

**The weird part:**
document.getElementsById does not exsist in JavaScript, so it can't work by default. The only way this can work is if somebody created this function/method on the other page. A more obvious explanation is that you made a type-o on your second page. Maybe you forgot to write the S and you thought you didn't. Can you try again?

Comment: I edited my post, for the first point it was just a type-o when I wrote the post, and I put the two javascript methods. And I can't find any custom method called getElementsById...

Comment: The line var estAvecGarantie = <bean:write property="avecGarantie" name="simulationAutonomeForm" filter="false"/>; is invalid. You can't use < or > here. Maybe you meant { of }?

Comment: It's a struts tag, it can be used here (because it's replaced server side), but it's not relevant.
I edited my post again, a part of the problem was the if clause on page B, and I corrected it before editing my post. I edited it back as it were when I had the problem.

Comment: is casChoix  equal to 'Emprunteur' or 'CoEmprunteur'? Because else the getElementsById function is never used. Thus giving you no error

Comment: It can be one or the other

Comment: So it is never something else?

Comment: Just to rule out that page B doesn't accidently use the function from Javascript A. Can you rename the function controleDelaiFranchise in page B to controleDelaiFranchiseB and call that function to test it?