# Can't filter search

Tags: javascript, html, search

I've been trying to get my search filter to work but can't get it to work. I'm a beginner but trying my best to make it work. Anyone out there that can help :)

The html

```
            <div class="notes_search">
                <input type="search" id="search_input" onkeyup="searchFilter()" placeholder="Search...">
            </div>

            <ul class="notes_list">
            </ul>

            <p class="notes_empty-msg">Nothing to show.</p>

        </section>

    </div>
```

The Script down bellow.

```
function searchFilter() {
    // Declare variables
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
    input = document.getElementsById('search');
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementsById('search')[0];
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");


    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter)===0) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `document.getElementsById` should be `document.getElementById` (it's singular).

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39367126/javascript-getelementbyid-vs-getelementsbyid-both-works-on-different-pages

Comment: You probably meant to use `querySelectorAll` instead.

Comment: Your textbox id is `search_input` and you are looking for `search`. Learn to use your debugger. The console clearly would point out your error with `getElementsById`

Comment: You also don't have any list items so I don't see how this will work at all.

Comment: And let me introduce you to "datalist" https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of issues with your code.

First, it's `getElementById` not `getElementsById`, but you might find using [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) easier to use as they match to CSS selectors (similar to jQuery).

Second, you don't have an element with a `search` id.

Third, your HTML contains no list items so it can't search for anything.

Here's a working version with annotations (using some more modern JS methods with which you might not be familiar but which can make the code more succinct). Note: it uses a class to make the items visible or not, and searches within the text content rather than just checking to see if it's at the start of the content which makes it a little more flexible.

```js
function searchFilter() {

  // You might find `querySelector` easier to use as it
  // allows you to correspond elements with CSS selectors
  const input = document.querySelector('#search');
  const filter = input.value.toUpperCase();

  const ul = document.querySelector('ul');
  const lis = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");

  for (i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {

    const item = lis[i];
    const itemContent = item.textContent.toUpperCase();

    // `textContent` might be more appropriate here
    // You can use the newer string method `includes`
    // to see if `filter` appears in the text content
    if (filter.length && itemContent.includes(filter)) {

      // Here I've used `classList` as the more modern
      // method way of adding and removing classes
      item.classList.add('visible');
    } else {
      item.classList.remove('visible');
    }

  }
  
}
```

```css
li { display: none; }
.visible { display: block }
```

```html
<div class="notes_search">
  <input type="search" id="search" onkeyup="searchFilter()" placeholder="Search...">
</div>

<ul class="notes_list">
  <li>Bob</li>
  <li>Sue</li>
  <li>Rita</li>
  <li>Rita and Bob</li>
  <li>John</li>
</ul>

<p class="notes_empty-msg">Nothing to show.</p>

</div>
```

Further reading

- [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)
- [`String.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)
- [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)

Comment: Thanks for the reply and help. I see the issue more clear now. I’m going to try and implement it and see how things workout :)

Answer (score 0):

You have several things here that are incorrect:

- It should be `getElementById` rather than getElementsById (not plural)
- Your input element has the id of "search_input", but you're trying to find an element with the name "search". When looking for an element, it should be **the exact name of id**, and not a partial word containing it. So try `input=document.getElementById('search_input');`
- Try using innerText rather than innerHtml: innerHtml returns in html format rather than plain text as I remember.

**index.html**

```
<div class="notes_search">
                <input type="search" id="search_input" onkeyup="searchFilter()" placeholder="Search...">
            </div>

            <ul class="notes_list">
              <li><a href = "/">hi</a></li>
              <li><a href = "/">hi</a></li>
              <li><a href = "/">bye</a></li>
            </ul>

            <p class="notes_empty-msg">Nothing to show.</p>

        </section>

    </div>
```

**index.js**

```
function searchFilter() {
    // Declare variables
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, text;
    input = document.getElementById('search_input');
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementsByClassName('notes_list')[0];
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");


    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        text = a.textContent || a.innerText;
        if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter)===0) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

I also added some **li** and **a** tag items to your html, since you didn't have them and it can't find tags that isn't on the html.

Comment: Thanks gonna try it out and see how it works out :)

Comment: Great :) Don’t forget to tick an answer you find the most useful as accepted

Answer (score 0):

I am not fully sure what you are trying to achieve but would a simple html datalist work for your problem:

```html
    <input list="your-choices" id="search_input" placeholder="Search...">

    <datalist id="your-choices">
        <option value="car">
        <option value="tree">
        <option value="street">
        <option value="sky">
        <option value="whatever">
    </datalist>
```

Comment: I’m building a note taking app. I see I’ve a long way to go with the learning part still. But thanks for the help and insight :)

Answer (score -5):

> You Can search by Jquery

```
var searchRequest = null;

$(function () {
    var minlength = 3;

    $("#sample_search").keyup(function () {
        var that = this,
        value = $(this).val();

        if (value.length >= minlength ) {
            if (searchRequest != null) 
                searchRequest.abort();
            searchRequest = $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "sample.php",
                data: {
                    'search_keyword' : value
                },
                dataType: "text",
                success: function(msg){
                    //we need to check if the value is the same
                    if (value==$(that).val()) {
                        //Receiving the result of search here
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Answer has nothing to do with OPs problem. Suggesting jQuery when there is no jQuery in the code is also not a good idea around here.