# How to get the Element ID in a for loop?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, createelement

Hello I have the following code:

```
function updateData() {

  var element = document.getElementById('elementId');
  element.remove(); ** //Here i want to remove my elements**

  return firebase.database().ref(varurl3).child('UserCount/count').once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
    var username = snapshot.val();


    for (var i = 1; i <= username; i++) {

      var ref = firebase.database().ref(varurl3).child('Users').child(i).child('User');
      ref.once('value', function(snapshot) {
        var changedPost = snapshot.val();
        var log = document.createElement('div');
        log.setAttribute('id', 'elementId');
        log.style.height = '75px';
        log.style.width = '300px';
        log.style.overflow = 'auto';
        log.style.border = '1px solid #666';
        log.style.backgroundColor = '#ccc';
        log.style.padding = '8px';
        log.style.position = 'relative';
        log.style.left = '1400px';
        log.style.top = '300px';
        log.style.margin = '10px';
        log.textContent = changedPost;
        document.body.appendChild(log)
      });
    }
  });
}

(async function looper() {
  while (true) { // forever
    await updateData();
    await delay(2000);
  }
})(); // execute looper
```

My function is called every 2 seconds to retrieve values from my firebase database and write them into divs every 2 seconds. Therefore i create with a for loop as many divs as i have values in my database. When the function is called again from new all div elements with the same ID should be deleted, so that they don't duplicate on the next run.

But these div elements are not deleted and I get the error message:

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: element is null

Could someone please help me how I can solve this problem?

Comment: You're using the same element id for every element you add, which does not make sense. Element ids must be **unique**.

Comment: Also `getElementById()` can return `null`; your code simply has to check for that condition.

Comment: "My function is called every 2 seconds to retrieve values from my firebase database and write them into divs every 2 seconds." That sounds incredibly wasteful. Did you consider using `on()` instead of `once()`, so Firebase actively calls your code when something changes - instead of you polling for updates?

Answer (score 0):

Element Ids need to be unique, so there is no way to fetch all elements with the same ID in one call.

You could try setting your divs to have a common tag, and use getElementsByTagName to collect them all up for deletion.

This post may be a useful reference: [Javascript: getElementById vs getElementsById (both works on different pages)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39367126/javascript-getelementbyid-vs-getelementsbyid-both-works-on-different-pages)