# How change href value after window loading

Tags: javascript

here is a `a` link with text:

```
<a id="linkk" href="/allgemeinen/sfsdf-sd-d-d-fd/"><p class="posttt">blablabla</p></a>
```

I want to delete nlinked after window loadend, here is js code:

```
    <script>
 window.onload = function() {
  var aEl = document.getElementById('linkk');
  aEl[0].href = "javascript:void(0)";
 };
 </script>
```

here is a example: `https://geburtstagsplanet.com/allgemeinen/sfsdf-sd-d-d-fd/`

but it doesn't work, why?

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns an array

Comment: That is because your page has `<a id="linkk" href=` not `<a class="linkk" href=` which means you either need to fix the class/id error or use `document.getElementById('linkk')` note the singular, id can exist only once: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885639/javascript-error-document-getelementsbyid-is-not-a-function

Comment: @zapl  how can  do it? Must i change it to id?

Comment: no, but when you use an id you can only change 1 element and you don't get an array returned, so ´elById.href` vs `elByClass[i].href`, `var els = document.getElementsByClassName('linkk'); for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) els.item(i).removeAttribute('href');` works for your page as it is for me. (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15843581/how-to-correctly-iterate-through-getelementsbyclassname - a `for in` loop fails)

Answer (score 0):

```
<srcipt>
 window.onload = function() {
  var aEl = document.getElementsByClassName('linkk');
  aEl[0].href = "javascript:void(0)";
 };
 </script>
```

or

```
<srcipt>
 window.onload = function() {
  var aEl = document.getElementsByClassName('linkk');
  aEl[0].removeAttribute('href');
};
</script>
```

Comment: not working:
https://geburtstagsplanet.com/allgemeinen/sfsdf-sd-d-d-fd/

Comment: see my page: https://geburtstagsplanet.com/allgemeinen/sfsdf-sd-d-d-fd/

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementsByClassName() returns a collection of elements. You probably need to refer to a specific element in the collection. So

```
aEl.href
```

should actually be

```
aEl[0].href
```

Comment: While your answer seems being technically correct it never mentions how to use the case like in the question with `aEl = document.getElementById('linkk')` correct. You might want to add that to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your open script tag is misspelled. Should be `<script>` not `<srcipt>`

Secondly, `getElementsByClassName` returns an array. If you are trying to do this operation for all links, you need to iterate over the result:

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    var aEl = document.getElementsByClassName('linkk');
    for(var link in aEl) {
        link.href = "javascript:void(0)";
    }
};
</script>
```

Also, if you are using `getElementsByClassName`, you should update your HTML accordingly:

```
<a class="linkk" href="/allgemeinen/sfsdf-sd-d-d-fd/"><p class="posttt">blablabla</p></a>
```

Comment: @InteressanteFakten Your HTML has `linkk` as an id and not a class.

Comment: yes but i also updateds your code, please see source doe of my page

Comment: can u  please check?

Comment: @InteressanteFakten If you look at your browser console, you might notice there are numerous javascript errors. These are probably preventing the `window.onload` method from firing. I suggest you address those before continuing.

Comment: @InteressanteFakten You need to look the errors in your browser console (Press F12, in most browsers) while on your site and try to fix the errors that are there. These are things beyond the code you are asking about.

Answer (score 0):

Below code should work.

```
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        const elem = document.getElementsByClassName('linkk');

        for( let i = 0; i < elem.length; i++ ){
            elem[i].href = '#';
        }
    }
</script>
```