# Changing background color by clicking a button

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I am learning JS and am trying to simply change the background color of a div when clicking on a button and wonder why my code isn't working.

Maybe somebody can take a quick look at the code below:

```js
let btnLeft = document.getElementsByClassName("left");
let btnRight = document.getElementsByClassName("right");
let ad = document.getElementById("ad");

btnLeft.addEventListener("click", changeTheBg());
btnRight.addEventListener("click", changeTheBg2());


function changeTheBg(){
   
ad.style.backgroundColor = "green";

};

function changeTheBg2(){
    
    ad.style.backgroundColor = "pink";
    
    };
```

```css
#ad {
width: 400px;
max-width: 500px;
height:200px;
background-color: red;
border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style.css">
</head>
<body>

<div id="ad"></div>

<div id="controls">
    <button class="left">Left
    </button>
    <button class="right">Right
    </button>
</div>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have at least three different problems here, all of which are duplicates.

Comment: Problem 1: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885639/javascript-error-document-getelementsbyid-is-not-a-function

Comment: Problem 2: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485244/window-onload-seems-to-trigger-before-the-dom-is-loaded-javascript

Comment: Problem 3: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485244/window-onload-seems-to-trigger-before-the-dom-is-loaded-javascript

Comment: btnLeft.addEventListener("click", changeTheBg);

Comment: Your 4th problem is that you don't seem to have looked at the error Console in your browser's developer tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several problems:

1. [`.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) takes a function "reference" as the
   second argument, you've passed a function "invocation" because
   you've added parenthesis after the function name:

   ```
   btnLeft.addEventListener("click", changeTheBg());
   ```

   As a result, your `changeTheBg` function is being invoked
   immediately and the return value from that function (nothing in this
   case) winds up being the reference for the callback.

   Simply remove the parenthesis:

   ```
   btnLeft.addEventListener("click", changeTheBg);
   ```
2. You've misspelled `getElementById()`, it's not `getElementsById()`.
3. [`.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns a collection of elements,
   not a single one, so trying to call `.addEventListener()` on the
   collection will fail. Instead use [`.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector), which
   returns the first element that matches the CSS selector passed to
   it, as in:

   ```
   let btnLeft = document.querySelector(".left");
   let btnRight = document.querySelector(".right");
   ```
4. `pinks` is not a valid color.

Here's the working code:

```js
let btnLeft = document.querySelector(".left");
let btnRight = document.querySelector(".right");
let ad = document.getElementById("ad");

btnLeft.addEventListener("click", changeTheBg);
btnRight.addEventListener("click", changeTheBg2);

function changeTheBg(){
  ad.style.backgroundColor = "green";
};

function changeTheBg2(){
  ad.style.backgroundColor = "pink";
};
```

```css
#ad {
  width: 400px;
  max-width: 500px;
  height:200px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="ad"></div>

<div id="controls">
    <button class="left">Left
    </button>
    <button class="right">Right
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: That only covers -one- two of the many problems with the code. It was already mentioned in a duplicate before you reopened the question.

Comment: @Quentin I addressed the first error I saw and posted, then was in the process of updating the answer when I spotted others. All errors have been identified now.

Comment: Thanks Everyone. It's my first day trying to get with js again, sorry for the uncareful errors!

Answer (score 1):

1. `getElementsByClassName` returns a live `NodeList`, use `querySelector(".classname")` instead (see Scott's comment and link for why not to use the NodeList!)
2. `getElementsById` is a typo and should be `getElementById` (singular), as you only select a single element via an id
3. you have to bind to the handler function name reference, not execute it via `()`
4. "pinks" is another typo and not a valid colour name, it should be "pink"

```js
let btnLeft = document.querySelector(".left");
let btnRight = document.querySelector(".right");
let ad = document.getElementById("ad");

btnLeft.addEventListener("click", changeTheBg);
btnRight.addEventListener("click", changeTheBg2);


function changeTheBg() {
  ad.style.backgroundColor = "green";
};

function changeTheBg2() {
  ad.style.backgroundColor = "pink";
};
```

```css
#ad {
  width: 400px;
  max-width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="ad"></div>
<div id="controls">
  <button class="left">Left
    </button>
  <button class="right">Right
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName returns a NodeList, from which you have to select e.g. the first item via index 0` <--- [**No, no, no!!**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54952088/how-to-modify-style-to-html-elements-styled-externally-with-css-using-js/54952474#54952474)