# Tempermonkey script: fandom login

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, tampermonkey

I want to tampermonkey script to login into a website. Enter username and password and click on submit button. So far I couldn't figure out how to do it.

Website: https://www.fandom.com/signin

Below code is what I have found by searching but isn't working.

```
    // ==UserScript==
// @name         Ghost
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        https://www.fandom.com/signin
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==


function username() {
  const firstInputElement = document.getElementsByID('loginUsername')[0];


  firstInputElement.oninput = (event) => {
    const inputValue = event.currentTarget.value;
    firstInputElement.value = /^[a-z]+/i.test(inputValue) ? 'username123' : ''
  };
}

username();

function password() {
  const firstInputElement = document.getElementsByID('loginPassword')[0];


  firstInputElement.oninput = (event) => {
    const inputValue = event.currentTarget.value;
    firstInputElement.value = /^[a-z]+/i.test(inputValue) ? 'password!123123' : ''
  };
}

password();


function login() {
    'use strict';

document.getElementsByClassName("form-submit")[0].click();
};

login();
```

Comment: Any help of for above question.

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByID` is not a javascript function.  You are looking for `document.getElementByID` singular.  [Javascript error - document.getElementsById is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885639/javascript-error-document-getelementsbyid-is-not-a-function)
Also since you are only going to return one element instead of a list of elements the `[0]` in `document.getElementByID('loginUsername')[0];` and `document.getElementByID('loginPassword')[0];` is not needed.